# Source Code Tab in Chrome Developer Tools no longer pops up the value when hovering over a variable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Suddenly I can no longer call up variable values ​​when hovering in the Source Code tab of Google Chrome's Developer Tools. Nothing happens. A few days ago everything was working fine. Current Chrome Version (105.0.5195.102)
What's weird: if I deploy a version and then try, everything works. It just doesn't work on localhost

If I use res in the callback function, I don't see a pop-up

[image]

Comment: Is it related to `*.jsx` files only? Does debugging of `*.js` have the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 105.0.5195.128, and it will not work with my bundled TS - code. It has always worked as it should.

But look.... I took a Demo Angular: https://ng-devtools.netlify.app/ , and somehow it works... but the popup is very different from what I'm used to.

[image: It seems that it is working here though]

Comment: anyone got a fix this is happening on 107 chrome version. so frustrating.

Comment: Try to clear the cache of google chrome i tried other Browser with the Blink environment and it worked as expected

Comment: @Sukh_Bains , I have similar issues with debugging `*.vue` in chrome dev tools while plain `*.js` has no issues at all. To see inline values of variable on mouse over, one has to select whole variable name (double click on variable) then variable value will be shown.